# Proper HTTP simulation

Tags: http

I am trying to simulate HTTP communication between client and server using simple TCP sockets - it works but not for all users. Some of them are dropped right when second message is sent.
I do send to server (message is base64 encoded):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: text/plain
Content-length: 4

AwEc
```

And respond from it:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK[trailing space here]
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 4

AwEc
```

If I send another message from client to server - connection is instantly dropped. What could I miss?

Comment: If you change `Keep-Alive` to `keep-alive` in the response, does that change anything?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you writing a HTTP client using raw socket APIs instead of high level ones? If this is the case, what's the HTTP server?

Comment: Client is written in AS3 (Flash) and uses URLStream to send HTTP requests (where I just specify that request is of type POST, set "contentType" property to "text/plain" and data (as for example it is set to "AwEc"). All other HTTP's fields are appeneded by Flash' itself (including Content-Length). If to be honest, Flash appends much more fields - such as Host, Referrer, Accept-Language and so on. That's why I cannot change lowercase "keep-alive" to uppercase in client request.

Comment: Server is written in C++, using simple TCP sockets upon Boost.Asio.